# Cannot access the setter of a parsed custom element

Tags: javascript, properties, custom-element

Here is a simple custom element:

```js
class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
  backingField;

  get property() { return this.backingField; }
  set property(value) {
    this.backingField = value;
    console.log("Inside Setter");
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = "<input>";

    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

window.customElements.define("test-element", TestElement);

// Parsing the element
const element = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<test-element></test-element>", "text/html").body.childNodes[0];

// Accessing the setter
element.property = "test";

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

When setting the property (`element.property = "test"`), `Inside Setter` should presumably be printed to the console. However, it does not.

When creating the element using `document.createElement()`, it works, but I need the element to be parsed.

How to solve this?

---

**Edit:**
When I set the property *after* appending the element to the `body`, it works:

```
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.property = "test";
```

I am not sure what is happening. I really need to set the property *before* it is appended to the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you created a custom element and registered it to the window, meaning it will be available in the page's DOM, (window.document).

However, how the DOMParser works is by creating another DOM object with its own data independent from the page DOM. Any custom elements you defined in the page DOM will not be accessible in this separate DOM.

If you want to take an element from the DOM created by the DOMParser and import it into the page DOM (without appending it), you can use the [`Document.importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) method.

From MDN:

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document) object's **`importNode()`** method creates a copy of a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node) or [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) from another document, to be inserted into the current document later.

---

So in your existing code, make sure to call this method before inserting the element into the document. This way, the custom element defined in the page's DOM will be recognized.

```js
const element = document.importNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString("<test-element></test-element>", "text/html").body.childNodes[0]);
element.property = "test";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Thank you! How come the element is rendered while unrecognized?

Comment: @MichaelHaddad If you mean how is it rendered by the DOMParser, as I explained, it is rendered in a separate document from the `window.document`. You could name the tag anything and it will still render, it will just lack the functionality you gave to the custom element.

Comment: More likely, you’ll have a template like this: `<template><form><my-input></my-input><my-input></my-input><my-select></my-select></form></template>`. In this case, something like `document.importNode(theTemplate.content.cloneNode(true), true).querySelector("form")`, with the second `deep` argument passed as `true`, is more helpful; the result is an `HTMLFormElement` with _all_ the (deeply nested) custom elements already working.